# Adding user in linux using tcl for FTP access

Tags: tcl, expect

I am new to script language world....and would need to add a user to my linux mc using tcl script for allowing allowing ftp access to that user. I tried

```
exec useradd -m username -p password
```

which does add a user but its ftp access using the username and password is not being allowed.
whereas,

```
adduser username
passwd username
```

allows FTP access but how can I program this interactive commands with tcl script which prompts for password, and editing the vsftpd conf file seems more complex using tcl script......Any suggestions would be helpful...Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to automate this is with the Expect extension. The [classic text on this matter](http://www.mel.nist.gov/msidlibrary/doc/libes94f.html) describes one way of doing it (looking just at the setting of the password; that's the tricky bit), but I think this is a little more elegant:

```
package require Expect

# You figure out how to get these...
set user "username"
set pass "whatever"

# Run the commands “as one” using a trick
spawn sh -c "adduser ${user}; passwd ${user}"
expect {
    "ssword: " {
        # This will handle *both* prompts...
        send "$pass\r"
        exp_continue;     # ... because we keep expecting
    }
    eof {
        # Do nothing; we're done now
    }
    timeout {
        # Shouldn't happen, but if the pattern is wrong...
        close
    }
}
```

If there are interactive parts of the `adduser` processing, you'll have to add clauses for them; just follow the general pattern of the `ssword:` clause and you'll be OK (remembering the `\r`; `\n` is not generally the same here!)

Comment: Thanks @Donal Fellows , but now I am having problem with package require expect ,My tcl(tclsh8.5) is unable to find it,eventhough follwing lines are included in my file test.tcl......
#!/usr/bin/expect.....
set auto_path /usr/bin/expect.....
package require Expect.....

puts [auto_execok expect].....
The puts returns /usr/bin/expect whenever I do ./test.tcl but on executing with /opt/ActiveTcl-8.5/bin/tclsh8.5 test.tcl its not happy with package require Expect.

Comment: @user3110438 If you've got the `expect` program installed, try using that to run the script instead of `tclsh`…